# Construct dictionary from mixed type list

Tags: python

I have the following list in python:

```
rooms = [1,'John','Mike','Simona',2,'Peter','Mark',3,'Olivia']
```

And I would like to convert it into a dictionary. The integers indicate the rooms and the names are strings:

```
rooms = {'room1': ['John','Mike','Simona'], 'room2': ['Peter','Mark'], 'room3': ['Olivia']}
```

How can I do that in an elegant way?

Comment: What if the first element is not in integer?

Comment: Good question. This would be an exception but we can leave this unhandled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could group by type, using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

grouped = groupby(rooms, type)
rooms = {}
for key, grp in grouped:
    roomname = 'room{}'.format(next(grp))
    rooms[roomname] = list(next(grouped)[1])
```

This segregates your input list into groups by object type. This gives you alternating groups of `int` and `str` values. The loop then retrieves the odd groups (the integers); the `next(grouped)` call in the loop body retrieves the even groups.

This does assume that a) your first value is a room number, and b) that a room number is never followed directly by another integer. If it is, those integers are ignored altogether.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> rooms = [1,'John','Mike','Simona',2,'Peter','Mark',3,'Olivia']
>>> grouped = groupby(rooms, type)
>>> rooms = {}
>>> for key, grp in grouped:
...     roomname = 'room{}'.format(next(grp))
...     rooms[roomname] = list(next(grouped)[1])
... 
>>> rooms
{'room2': ['Peter', 'Mark'], 'room3': ['Olivia'], 'room1': ['John', 'Mike', 'Simona']}
```

Comment: Clever use of `type` there :)

Comment: Note: if sort is important use [`oredereddict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 2):

The following will help you.

```
rooms = [1,'John','Mike','Simona',2,'Peter','Mark',3,'Olivia']

new_dict = {}

for value in rooms:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        ID = "room"+str(value)        
    else:
        new_dict.setdefault(ID, []).append(value)

print new_dict
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'room1': ['John', 'Mike', 'Simona'], 'room2': ['Peter', 'Mark'], 'room3': ['Olivia']}
```

Comment: Why the `while` loop with an incrementing `index` when you could just use a `for` loop here?

Comment: No, just loop over `rooms` directly; the `range()` is not needed here. `for value in rooms:`. Note that to test for integers, you really should use `isinstance()` here. `if isinstance(value, int):`.

Comment: Edited again... Learning a lot from you. :)